# Можно ли соединить информацию из разных процессов в 1 список

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Необходимо объединить списки из 4 процессов в 1, возможно ли это и как это сделать?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    if length % cpus == 0:
        pass
    proc_1 = Process(target=get_mes, args=(m_id[0:length//2],1,))#m_id[0:length//2
    proc_1.start()
    proc_2 = Process(target=get_mes, args=(m_id[length // 2*2:(length // 2)*3], 2,))
    proc_2.start()
    proc_3 = Process(target=get_mes, args=(m_id[length // 2*3:(length // 2)*4], 4,))
    proc_3.start()
    get_mes(m_id[length//2:(length//2)*2],0)
```

Comment: Судя по тому, что Вы во всех процессах используете одну и ту-же функцию с разным набором аргументов, я бы посоветовал использовать Pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Пример к коментарию

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import randint


def simple_rand(a, b, c):
    return (a + b + c) * randint(2, 5)


item_list = [(1, 3, 5,), (8, 9, 10)] * 50

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(8) as pool:
        new_item_list = [item for item in pool.starmap(simple_rand, item_list)]

    print(new_item_list)
```

## UPD:

> на счет разбить на части (хотя это уже другой вопрос)

```py
lst = [5] * 15


def chunks(iterable, chunk_size: int):
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), chunk_size):
        yield iterable[i:i + chunk_size]


print([item for item in chunks(lst, len(lst) // 4 + bool(len(lst) % 4))])
# [[5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: А если у меня будут разные процессы?

Comment: @Bubunduc, Вы имеете ввиду разные функции с различающимся набором параметров? Если да, то я бы рекометовал Вам рассмотрть asyncio

Comment: @Bubunduc, ну или можно рассмотреть запись из процессов в БДэху типа sqlite с последующим чтением оттуда

Comment: А как поделить список на 4 равные части, для того чтобы воспользоваться пулом(в моем случае)?

Comment: @Bubunduc, обновил, равными списки будут при длине кратной четырем

Comment: @Bubunduc, почитайте про Pool, у меня складывается впечатление, что Вы не до конца понимаете как оно работает, или я не понимаю как работает Ваш скрипт

Comment: Да, я только учусь пользоваться процессами

Comment: у меня 1 большой список делится на 4 маленьких, обрабатывается в 4 разных процессах, а потом из них снова собирается 1 большой(по крайней мере так задумано)

Comment: @Bubunduc, при помощи Pool Вы можете обрабатывать один большой спсок в от 1-х до 63-х потоков. (Количество потоков указывается при инициализации Pool. Pool(16) означает в 16 потоков. Будет гораздо легче Вам помочь если вы добавите в вопрос образцы входных и выходных данных